# Can a black hole absorb vacuum energy?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, black-holes, energy-conservation, vacuum

Can a macroscopic black hole absorb vacuum energy from the surroundings, and thereby increase its mass?

Answer (score 1):

Vacuum energy is a concept from quantum field theory, wherein even the "empty" vacuum of space is subject to fluctuations due to the inherent uncertainty in the properties of quantum fields. These fluctuations are thought to give rise to a nonzero "vacuum energy".

Black Holes
In the context of general relativity, black holes are regions of spacetime where gravity is so strong that not even light can escape from them. Their mass increases when they absorb matter or energy.

Vacuum Energy and Black Holes
The idea of a black hole absorbing vacuum energy to gain mass is not a standard concept in either quantum field theory or general relativity. In fact, the prevailing theory, known as the Hawking radiation mechanism, suggests that black holes should gradually lose mass over time due to quantum effects near the event horizon, rather than gaining it.

Moreover, vacuum energy is typically considered to be a property of spacetime itself, uniformly distributed, and not something that can be "absorbed" by objects, even black holes.

Answer (score 0):

No. The exact solution is known ([de Sitter-Schwarzschild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter%E2%80%93Schwarzschild_metric)) for a black hole in a universe with a cosmological constant (equivalent to vacuum energy). The black hole in this solution does not grow.

Comment: Thx a lot :) What if dark energy is not constant, but increasing?